# How can I get Opportunity URL?

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, opportunity, query

I'm trying to get some data from salesforce to my Google SpreadSheet with Google Apps Script.
I have such a request

```
SELECT o.ID, o.Name, a.name, o.Amount, o.StageName, o.CloseDate, o.CreatedDate FROM opportunity o, o.Account a
```

And I also need to get an URL to Opportunity Edit Page,

```
https://SERVER_ID.salesforce.com/OPPO_ID
```

How can i get it?
Thanks

Comment: You want this on VF page OR Class?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to SalesForce so I don;t understand your question. I'm using Google Apps Script And I think this is just a REST request to `/services/data/v37.0/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit url is the easy part. In `Apex` you can build them more programmatically, but the following should always work:

```
https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/Opportunity_Id/e
```

---

As for the query, if you want to pull data via the `REST API`:

> ### [Execute a SOQL Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)
>
> Use the Query resource to execute a SOQL query that returns all the results in a single response, or if needed, returns part of the results and an identifier used to retrieve the remaining results.
>   The following query requests the value from name fields from all Account records.
>
> Example usage for executing a query
>
> ```
> curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ### Retrieving the Remaining SOQL Query Results
>
> If the initial query returns only part of the results, the end of the response will contain a field called nextRecordsUrl. For example, you might find this attribute at the end of your query:
>
> ```
> "nextRecordsUrl" : "/services/data/v20.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000"
> ```
>
> In such cases, request the next batch of records and repeat until all records have been retrieved. These requests use nextRecordsUrl, and do not include any parameters.
>
> Example usage for retrieving the remaining query results
>
> ```
> curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000 -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
> ```

Note that you don't need to reference `o.` (e.g. `o.Field1`, `o.Field2`) and can drop those from your query. Also note that you can only have one object in your `FROM` clause. You can't select from both `Opportunity` and `Account` both. You can pull data from `Account` records related to your query through a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join). Simple example:

```
SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity
```